# Word order in the sentences with 'I wonder'

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, terminology, sentence

I do not know the correct terminology for phrases that contain the 'I wonder' bit. I do, however, realise that most of the time the word order in such sentences is supposed to be sort of 'reversed', e.g.

Who are you? -> I wonder who you are.
Where is my car? -> I wonder where my car is.
Why are you late? -> I wonder why you are late.
etc...

But what about a sentence like 'Who is making all this noise?'?
It acts differently from the other examples, if I'm not mistaken.
Take this sentence, for instance:

'Who are you?' -> 'I wonder who you are.'
This one is very clear.

'Who is there?' -> 'I wonder who there is?' OR 'I wonder who is there'.
Which one would be correct?

I would love to know if there is a definite answer to how sentences like those tend to act, and also would like to find out more about the terminology behind them, as I struggle to place the object and the predicate in the sentences, for example.

Comment: You will find that when the _Wh-_ question word is the subject of the question, it doesn't hafta move, and so neither does the auxiliary verb. The questions with syntax that takes heavy machinery are the ones where the _Wh-_ word refers to something that's very far away from the subject.

Comment: See [Embedded Questions in Grammar](https://www.thoughtco.com/embedded-question-grammar-1690588) at ThoughtCo.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the term that you are looking for to describe the "I wonder" part is "matrix clause".

In each of your examples, the verb "wonder" takes a nominal (content) clause as its direct object. The word that introduces the nominal clause ("who", "where", etc.) gets "fronted" (i.e., moved to first position in that clause), and the rest of the clause follows in typical SVO word order:

> I wonder **where** my car is.
> I wonder **why** you are late.
> I wonder **who** you are.

Of course, the introductory word can itself be the subject, and we still use SVO word order:

> I wonder **who** is making all this noise.
> I wonder **who** is there.

The last example uses the standard adverbial "there". We could also use the so-called existential or dummy "there", which itself gets fronted (but not before the other fronted elements), though it sounds a bit unusual in this particular context:

> Somebody is there. -> Is somebody there? -> I wonder **who** is there.
> There is somebody. -> Is there somebody? -> I wonder **who** there is.